# Русский язык, морфемика

Tags: словообразование

Какое окончание в слове "бесплатный"?

Comment: Ну, трудно ли подглядеть в словарь? https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Answer (score 2):

Это окончание - ый. В этом можно убедиться, если просклонять это слово. Им.пад.бесплатн**ый**, род. пад. бесплатн**ого**, и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

> Какое окончание в слове...

Чтобы определить и выделить в слове окончание, надо изменить его: ***«трава – травы», «лечу – летит», «новый – новее»***. Часть слова, остающаяся без изменения, является основой: ***«трав-», «леч-» «нов-»***, **а та, что изменяется, – окончанием**.

Подробнее: http://www.kakprosto.ru/kak-130292-kak-nayti-v-slove-okonchanie-i-osnovu#ixzz3p9BQTyAQ